# Ruby program for managing locker reservations

Tags: ruby, class, oop, object, data-structures

I am stuck on a problem that is a bit too advanced for me. I really want to push through this problem and find a solution but not sure how to go about it.

Here is the problem:

Write a program for managing locker reservations at a hotel concierge desk. 
    Customers leave bags with the concierge, who then uses your program to determine 
    in which locker to place the bag. The program tells the concierge the number of 
    the locker in which to place the bag, and prints a ticket to give to the customer. 
    Upon return, the customer provides the ticket, and the concierge uses that to 
    look up the corresponding locker, retrieve the bag, and return it to the customer.

There are 1000 small lockers, 1000 medium sized lockers, 
and 1000 large lockers (it’s a big Vegas hotel). You can assume that all 
checked bags fit into one of these three sizes. The program should
always assign the smallest available locker that fits the bag.

Can someone give me some guidance as to how to approach a problem like this? I am good at writing Ruby scripts but now trying to really understand OOP principles. It would be helpful if you can create the first 2 or 3 methods in a class for me to see where you begin. Also, how you break down this problem into more manageable chunks and how you store data in variable/format that different classes can easily use.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To model this problem we can use classes called `Locker` and `Bag` which represent the domain objects (i.e. the actual objects the application will be handling).

The `Locker` objects can have status flags to determine what kind of locker it is (small, medium, or large), and the same goes for the `Bag` objects. Our two classes can look like this:

```
class Locker
  attr_reader :type, :id
  attr_accessor :bag

  def initialize(id, type = nil)
    raise ArgumentError, "Id not present" if id.nil?
    @id = id
    @type = type
    @bag = nil
  end

  def free?
    !@bag
  end

  def can_place(bag)
    return false unless free?
    case bag.type
      when :small
        true
      when :medium
        @type != :small
      when :large
        @type == :large
      else
        # invalid type
        false
      end
  end

end 


class Bag
  attr_reader :type

  def initialize(type = nil)
    @type = type
  end
end
```

The `initialize` method will be called whenever you create a new object (`Bag.new` or `Locker.new` in our case).

So, there we have our two domain objects, but we still need to have something to run our actual program. This can be called anything you want, but for our purpose let's just call it `locker_app` per the ruby naming conventions.

```
require './locker'
require './bag'

BAG_LIMIT = 1000
lockers = []

for i in 0..BAG_LIMIT do
  lockers[i] = Locker.new(i, :small)
  lockers[i+BAG_LIMIT] = Locker.new(i+BAG_LIMIT, :medium)
  lockers[i+2*BAG_LIMIT] = Locker.new(i+2*BAG_LIMIT, :large)
end

while true do

  puts "please enter bag size"
  type = gets.strip!.to_sym
  bag = Bag.new(type)
  start = 0

  begin
    case type
    when :small
    when :medium
      start = BAG_LIMIT
    when :large
      start = 2*BAG_LIMIT
    else
      raise ArgumentError, "please select a proper size"
    end

    for i in start..lockers.size-1
      locker = lockers[i]
      if locker.free? && locker.can_place(bag)
        locker.bag = bag
        puts i
        break
      end
      puts "Sorry, no available lockers" if locker == lockers.last
    end 
  rescue ArgumentError => e
    puts e.message
  end

end
```

This simple program runs in an infinite loop (`while true`) and waits for user input on each iteration trough the [Kernel.gets](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.2.2/Kernel.html) method. The user can then type in a bag type (small, medium, or large) and the program will output the number for the locker.

The lockers are created sequentially at the start of the program, with small lockers in indexes from 0-999, medium from 1000 - 1999, and large from 2000 - 2999. Bags are then placed in lockers based on the type of bag.

You can run it in your own console to verify that it works by running `ruby locker_app.rb`. The code can also be viewed [here](https://gist.github.com/nicohvi/4f0c95f078d82123ca27).

This is a naïve implementation, and should be taken as a starting point. There are several different directions you could go from here (for instance numbering the lockers with a `1`-index rather than `0`-indexed like in my example, or maintaining a list of how many bags are currently stored, and so on.

The general idea behind this design is to have classes describe the objects in your problem, and then build the glue between these objects (in this example, `locker_app` is that glue). I'm a firm believer in first creating something that **just works**, and then work on making it better incrementally.

Please do not hesitate to ask if you have any questions.

Comment: main.rb:36:in `block in <main>': undefined method `bag=' for #<Locker:0x25b94b0 @size=:small, @bag=nil, @id=1> (NoMethod
Error)
        from main.rb:33:in `each'
        from main.rb:33:in `<main>'

Comment: do you know what the problem is?

Comment: This means that there is no method in the `Locker` class that allows you to set the `bag` variable. Please ensure that you have `attr_accessor :bag` line in your `Locker` class.

Comment: ahh i only had attr_reader. I added an attr_writter and fixed it thanks!

Comment: No worries! Please let me know if you have any questions about the structure of objects, or how they interact with each other. :)